# nuget - missing staticwebassets folder after custom pack

Tags: c#, blazor, nuget, nuget-package, razor-class-library

I am building a shared library as RCL where my components are located and can be shared in several applications.
This library contains "global" styles as well as "component-bound (isolated)" styles.

When consuming this nuget-package the css should be found under `_content/shared.razorcomponents.server/css/components.css` (located under the RCL's `wwwroot\css` folder) as well as `_content/shared.razorcomponents.server/shared.razorcomponents.server.bundle.scp.css` (for the isolated styles).

When building my RCL with `<GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>` I can examine the generated nupkg file.
It contains my `components.css` under `RazorComponents.Server.1.0.0.zip\staticwebassets\css`.

After building the nuget through azure pipeline and adding the package to my "consuming" application I got 404 for the referenced style-sheets.

Examing the local package-store under `%userprofile%\nuget\packages\shared.razorcomponents.server\1.0.45\` the `staticwebassets` folder is gone and the css I am looking for is located under `shared.razorcomponents.server\1.0.45\content\wwwroot\css`.

Any idea why the `staticwebassets` folder has been wiped or how I can reference my RCL's styles from the nuget?

Comment: Is this a blazor server-side or web-assembly application? In program startup there are options to explicitly use static assets. For example in WASM: ```app.UseStaticFiles();```